# Raising the Answer Text Limit

Tags: feature-request

Today I was working on one of the answers (A special guide) and I was limited again by the 30K size for answers. The example mentioned is this:

[How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/installing-nvidia-drivers)

Which I needed to add some info but to do that I had to remove other information that helped older users. This is not the only case where I need to limit the amount of helpful information to serve users. There are others like the following that I can not extend to cover some special cases:

[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported)

[How to enable or disable services?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19320/how-to-enable-or-disable-services)

[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

[How to install and configure Wine?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/316025/installing-and-configuring-wine)

[How to install Minecraft (Client)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/225432/how-to-correctly-install-and-troubleshoot-minecraft-client)

I am asking for a feature-request to raise the cap to about 35k or more. For answers that extend further (Like answering how to install and configure Juju, Hadoop...) or a correct and complete guide on how to install Ubuntu including partitioning. I know 30K is enough for most cases but there are this type of answers that to explain them thoroughly they need more than 30K. This can ease the time Ubuntu end users take jumping between questions/answers trying to find what they are looking for and eliminating many similar but different common questions/answers.

For example, I am at the moment working on improving the whole Broadcom guide but between one of the writers and me, the amount will surpass the 30K limit easily and the idea is to provide a one stop solution to most Broadcom Wifi problems (Same for the rest of the questions).

Comment: You could try splitting it into two answers.  Not ideal, but it works.

Comment: Man, those answers are too huge! For example you are trying to answer _10 questions_ in that nvidia answer. That's not how the site is designed!

Comment: @JorgeCastro I would humbly disagree my good sir. I believe users  find it better to cover most common problems related to particular subject in one answer than doing a lot of searching to find that one answer only covers half of what they are looking for (Which happened a lot in the past for questions like the one mentioned above). There should be more questions that cover in a complete way how to solve particular problems. For example http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it which handles pretty well all common problems.

Comment: I'm not against your feature request, however I see 2 problems: 1.) Your answer has a lot of upvotes and covers a lot of problems in detail, **but** it is hard to find and to use as a resource for similar questions, which leads to users asking the same question in a slightly different wording over and over. (You're also covering AMD graphics, but one wouldn't read answers on a question that is titled with Nvidia.) 2.) I think that answers as well as questions should deal with problems in **consumable** and easily **expandable** chunks. Not leading to RTFM and "HowToAskQuestionsTheSmartWay".

Comment: Alternatively: Think of every question and (accepted) answer as a module in a flexible and interchangeable module in a solution chain to answer complex individual problems. Ideally the redundancy among answers should be low. Not every user should need to write his own essay or wikipedia-sized article to provide a good answer to a simple problem - it shouldn't be about quantity, but solving problems quick and efficient. At least that's what I would want if I were searching and asking.

Comment: @LiveWireBT Actually the Intel/Ati information was removed. I still need to remove another piece and only point to the most popular Ati/Intel questions for this, but I see/like your point there.

Comment: One important question for stackexchange: Would it require a DB schema change?  It's totally not worth a schema change stack wide for not breaking up your awesome answers in to multiple answers...

Comment: @hbdgaf Well that's a very important question. In that case I would start dividing up answers but would have to edit questions to point to each section/answer as mentioned by Seth. Too much hassle to do a DB change just for this I would think.